Overview of quantization of gauge theories
I've searched for this topic and I want to know whether following statements are correct:

Peierls bracket, presymplectic formalism and Dirac bracket gives equivalent presymplectic form on phase space.

To quantize a gauge theory, we can either (1) replace Dirac brackets of gauge-invariant functions by commutators, (2) quantize reduced phase space, (3) fix the gauge and then quantize the theory or (4) use BRST quantization.

Mathematically, reduced phase space means symplectic quotient (=Marsden-Weinstein quotient) by the gauge group action.

BRST quantization is equivalent to the quantization of reduced phase space.


And one more... if the second statement is true, is it possible to quantize free Maxwell theory using Dirac bracket, without gauge fixing? I ask this because all the documents I found for quantization of Maxwell theory uses either gauge fixing or BRST formalism.

Related: Has the conjecture of Guillemin-Sternberg been proven for relevant physics cases?

@Qmechanic thank you for the keyword "Guillemin Sternberg Conjecture"... I searched it and found it states "quantization of symplectic reduction is eqaul to ..." so probably statement 2-(2) and 3 might be true. However, as it is a conjecture, I guess these kinds of question is not very well-founded yet...
